# coding matrix of child elements in php

Tags: php, html, css

Given values of variables $n, $m and $gap.

I want to display a matrix of equal red rectangles, having dimensions of $m rows and $n columns. Vertical and horizontal spaces between the rectangles will be $gap percent of the parent element's width and height respectively. Same size will have the margins of the matrix to the parent's edge.

For example for $n=2 and $m=3 this is the desired outcome:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$n=2; //axis x
$m=3; //axis y
$gap=10% //percent of the parent's dimension

$childwidth=round((100-$gap*($n+1))/$n);
$childheight=round((100-$gap*($m+1))/$m);

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>hey I am a title</title>
    <style>
       body{margin:0px;}
       .parent, html, body{width: 100%; height: 100%;}
       .parent{margin: <?php echo $gap; ?>% <?php echo $gap; ?>% 0 0;}
       .child{margin: 0% 0% <?php echo $gap; ?>% <?php echo $gap; ?>% ; width: <?php echo $childwidth; ?>%; height: <?php echo $childheight; ?>%; background-color: #a00;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    

<div class=parent>
    <div class=child>e</div>
    <div class=child>r</div>
    <div class=child></div>
    <div class=child></div>
    <div class=child></div>
    <div class=child></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Could I please have an advice how to finish it? Thank you.

I work with percentages of the parent element. If it would be necessary to work with pixels instead, I have this code that enables to get window dimension into a php variable (window=parent in my case).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie = 'window_width='+window.innerWidth+'; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2901 20:47:11 UTC; path=/';
    document.cookie = 'window_height='+window.innerHeight+'; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2901 20:47:11 UTC; path=/';
</script>


<?php
echo "inner: ";
echo $_COOKIE['window_width']."x";
echo $_COOKIE['window_height'];
?>
```

Comment: You start by talking about a parent element but then you move to talking about window dimensions - which do you want to use for the width and height of the grid - parent width and height or window width and height or .... I can't see the relevance of window dimensions.

Comment: Well first I intended to solve that for parent=window, but later I realized that a greater fun would be to solve it for any parent element.

Comment: OK, thanks, undetstood. So what is the actual problem with what you've got so far? I notice that there are missing quotes around the class names, but is there something else you want?

Comment: My code doesn't work, as you might notice. How would you approach such a problem? Thank you.

Comment: After I'd got the syntax right (in this case the quotes round the classes) I'd run the code and in my browser use the dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what values had been set in the classes and if they didn't look right, look at the calculation being done in the PHP.

Comment: The calculation is correct. The current code displays all the childs in one column.

Comment: Well, you want your children to be inline-blocks and I don't see how the calculation is completely correct for everything - look at the settings of margins for example. There is no relevance to setting the margins of the parent to $gap%.

Comment: I think there it should be padding instead of the margin...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that all you need is a fairly straightforward css `grid` (using `display: grid` and `gap` and the like).
Here's some [examples on how to use it](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/).